# Flask peewee database is locked on production server

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, peewee

I built a website using Flask that uses peewee SQLite database. this is how open and close the database on requests

```py
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([Post, User], safe=True)


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    db.close()
    return response
```

But sometime I am getting "database is locked" error. this is happening when 2 or more users using the website.

Comment: Sqlite only allows one writer per connection. https://charlesleifer.com/blog/multi-threaded-sqlite-without-the-operationalerrors/

Comment: Thanks, a lot. using SqliteQueueDatabase solved the locking issue.

Comment: That is a drastic solution, though -- you might also read through the transaction details here: https://charlesleifer.com/blog/going-fast-with-sqlite-and-python/